# How many years Magento 2 certificate is valid?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.2.2, associatedevelopercertification

How many years Magento 2 certificate is valid?

How much time it will take to prepare for Magento 2 exam?

If Magento upgraded to magento 3 4...then the certificate is acceptable or not?

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 developer certificate is valid for 24 months and it's valid for only magento2 as the name suggests.

My opinion minimum preparation time is 6 month.

Answer (score 0):

How many years Magento 2 certificate is valid?
--> It is valid for Two years only.

How much time it will take to prepare for Magento 2 exam?
--> Depending upon you, it will take upto 3 months if you are preparing in good way.

If Magento upgraded to magento 3 4...then the certificate is acceptable or not?
--> No, Magento 2 certification is valid only for Magento 2